# Cannot display pdf (xxx.pdf is of invalid format)

Tags: android, pdf

when i click view pdf from application it works fine on PC but  unable to view pdf on Galaxy 6s phone showing "Cannot display pdf (xxx.pdf is of invalid format)"

Comment: Have you tried opening it with an other app to be sure that the pdf file is not damaged ?

Comment: when tried opening  in other app in mobile it get downloaded and able to view

Comment: Then I think you do not download it correctly. Can you add your code ?

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: Having the same =(

Answer (score 0):

Programatically you (or the programmer) have to define a mime type for the PDF "application/pdf". If it is not defined, then the Application that tries to open, fails on that showing that message.